# Unity + EntityFramework + PRISM - "Resolution of the dependency failed"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, unity-container, prism

Im new on Unity/EF world and im getting a Error when i execute my test new project.

I have a Prism bootstrap first:

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return new Shell();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();


        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        this.Container
            .RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, SistemaContext>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
            .RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())


            .RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<Cliente>, Repository<Cliente>>()
            .RegisterType<IClienteService, ClienteService>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

        ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(CadastroModule.CadastroModule));
    }
}
```

And other project "CadastroModule" with the CadastroModule:

```
public class CadastroModule : IModule
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

        public CadastroModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(Views.CadastroCliente));
        }
    }
```

Thats my EF Context:

```
public class SistemaContext : Sistema.Common.Repository.DataContext
{
    static SistemaContext()
    {//I dont know what to do here!
        //Database.SetInitializer<SistemaContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SistemaContext, Sistema.DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration>());
    }
    public SistemaContext()
        : base("Name=ContactsDb")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Sistema.DataAccess.Mapping.ClienteConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Sistema.DataAccess.Mapping.EnderecoConfig());
    }
}
```

I need the "MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion" for automatic migrations.

The View:

```
public partial class CadastroCliente : UserControl
{
    private readonly IClienteService _clienteService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public CadastroCliente()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public CadastroCliente(IClienteService clienteService, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _clienteService = clienteService;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgv.DataContext = _clienteService.ClienteOrdenadoNome();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1 IF i take out the IUnitOfWork it runs!**:

```
public partial class CadastroCliente : UserControl
{
    private readonly IClienteService _clienteService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public CadastroCliente()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public CadastroCliente(IClienteService clienteService)
    {
        _clienteService = clienteService;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgv.DataContext = _clienteService.ClienteOrdenadoNome();
    }
}
```

---

**Im using a Generic unit of Work repository located here: [Link](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/releases/view/113204)**

And the Error is this:

> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>   Resolving CadastroModule.Views.CadastroCliente,(none)
>   Resolving parameter \"unitOfWork\" of constructor CadastroModule.Views.CadastroCliente(Sistema.Service.IClienteService clienteService, Sistema.Common.Repository.UoW.IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
>   Resolving Sistema.Common.Repository.UoW.IUnitOfWork,(none)

**I detected when the UnitOfWork is taking the context**

> public class UnitOfWork : UnitOfWorkAsync
>   public UnitOfWork(IDataContextAsync dataContext) { _dataContext = dataContext; }

**The dataContext return a internal exception exception:**

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. 
>   This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. 
>   Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe

**What im doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved after many days...
Internaly of the RepositoryFramework that im using, the EntityClasses need to inherit from a class named Entity:

```
public abstract class Entity : IObjectState
{
    [NotMapped]
    public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
}
```

A child "Complex"(Entity framework Mapping ComplexTypeConfiguration<***>) class, was not inherited.
The error was not the UNIT/PRISM, was the repository itself that im using.
To resolve that i created a new project using no Modularity PRISM to be more simple to find where the error is comming.

So... my problem was resolved by putting the ": Entity" on my Child class:

```
public class Endereco : Entity //HERE
{
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }

}
```